# Communicating between OpenMP threads

Tags: c++, openmp

I have an OpenMP loop where I want the first iteration to complete before any of the other threads continue. I've tried using a global variable, initialized to 'false', which is set to 'true' when the first iteration finishes, but this doesn't appear to work as expected (I get stuck in an infinite loop).

For example:

```
    bool FirstDone = false; // This is a global variable
    ...
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(int i=0;i<max;i++)
    {
        while(!FirstDone && i>0){}

        if(i==0)
        {
            // Do something
            FirstDone = true;
        }
    }
```

Can anyone shed light on why this isn't working?

Comment: Shouldn't FirstDone be labelled as shared ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do first iteration outside the loop, start for with i=1, if you want to proceed with your logic, change FirstDone to volatile, but it still will not work, as there is no guarantee of thread ordering

Comment: I would *much* prefer to do it inside the loop via some sort of barrier on the i>0 threads. The loop is just fairly long and complex... copying the entire contents just to do the i=0 step outside seems clunky to me.

Comment: Actually, making FirstDone volatile and adding 'ordered' to the #pragma omp parallel for line seems to work.. although I am fearful that it's only working on my local machine with 2 threads.

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap the first iteration inside an OpenMP `single` construct. This will ensure that the first thread to encounter the construct will execute it and that all the other threads will wait until it is finished before continuing with the rest of the computation.

Comment: This introduces a race condition - the i=0 thread must hit that single construct before any others to work as intended.

Comment: @paradiso No, this is the right thing to do: the `i = 0` __iteration__ has to be executed before the other iterations, whichever thread executes it!

Comment: @Massimiliano can you explain how this would be implemented? It still appears to me that the `i!=0` iterations could still begin executing before `i=0` hits the critical code (which is half-way down the loop)

Comment: @paradiso See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

I'll try here to rephrase the answer of @HighPerformanceMark in a more explicit manner (i.e. with some code sketches to support statements). Just to fix ideas, let's say that a serial version of your loop looks like:

```
for(int ii = 0; ii < max; ii++)
{   
    // Do a lot of work based on ii
    if(ii==0)
    {
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Do something special for the first iteration //
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////
    }
}
```

What was briefly proposed in a previous answer was to parallelize it with this simple logic

```
// Move the loop body into a function
void loopIteration(const size_t ii) {
    // Do a lot of work based on ii
}

#pragma omp parallel
{
// Single directive: the first one enters, the other wait at the implicit barrier
#pragma omp single
    {
        loopIteration(0);
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Do something special for the first iteration //
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////
    } // single: implicit barrier
// Loop work-sharing construct on the remaining iterations
#pragma omp for
    for(int ii = 1; ii < max; ii++)
    {   
       loopIteration(ii);         
    } // for: implicit barrier
} // parallel
```

The main ideas are to move the loop body into a function to avoid code duplication and to unroll explicitly the first iteration from the loop.

Comment: Ah so you do mean to put the main loop code in an external function. I appreciate the idea - and understand that it would work - but it is unwieldy in my case. I have many shared variables which *could* be passed by reference, but it would make for a very long function signature. I've been using @Ilya Bursov's solution with a 'volatile' boolean and it seems to be a fine solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use this one

```
 #pragma omp parallel for
```

it starts by default with your first iteration.

Comment: I don't agree. Can you explain more or provide some references?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve this by using an `ordered` clause and region, eg.

```
#pragma omp parallel for ordered
for(int i=0;i<max;i++)
{
    #pragma omp ordered
    if (i == 0)
    {
        // Do stuff in the first iteration, others wait.
    }

}
```

This may incur a performance overhead.

Comment: It's not 100% clear to me that this would work, but it's my favorite option so far.. I'll try it out in a bit

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply removing the.empty while loop and setting a barrier after the if statement ?

Comment: Totally reasonable solution, although in my particular case I can't put the if statement at the top of the loop (despite my code sample having it placed there)

Comment: You can't put a barrier after the `if` statement as you can't ensure that every thread will encounter the same sequence of barriers (and this will make the program non conforming to the standard)

Comment: @Massimiliano can you elaborate ? Why can't I put a barrier after     if(i==0)
        {
            // Do something
            FirstDone = true;
        }

Comment: Because `The sequence of worksharing regions and barrier regions encountered must be the same for every thread in a team.` (you'll find this sentence in many places in the OpenMP 3.1 standard). Think of 10 iterations divided among 3 threads: there is no way in which you can ensure that they meet at the barrier the same number of time.

Comment: @Massimiliano Ok, with unbalanced work, I get it. Thx